# Aspose.Words - Format a single word in a paragraph

Tags: ms-word, aspose.words

I'm new to Aspose.Words for .Net, and working on recreating some documents for a customer. I need to make a single word in a paragraph bold and underlined.  I'm trying to achieve this by creating separate paragraph runs for the text before the bold word, the bold word itself, and the text after.  Then I'm formatting the bold word's run and appending everything to the paragraph.  This seems overly complicated.  Is there a simple way to achieve this from within DocumentBuilder.WriteLn("some text")?

Answer (score 1):

I kept working at it, and achieved the desired result by using DocumentBuilder.Write() instead of DocumentBuilder.Writeln():

```
builder.Write("The start of the paragraph ");
builder.Font.Bold = true;
builder.Font.Underline = Underline.Single;
builder.Write("underlined bolded text");
builder.Font.Bold = false;
builder.Font.Underline = Underline.None;
builder.Write(" the end of the paragraph.");
```